# Is it possible to set different id in struts radio tag

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, struts, jsp-tags

I am new to struts, I get "java.lang.NullPointerException" when I click on my radio buttons.
I have two different types of users(Central & Local) which are mapped to different radio buttons.
I also have a Drop-Down box on my form. I want to make it disable for central users.

I just know that the properties must be same in tags  to make a radio group, but what could be the properties in my case? I tried many ways before, but still get NullPointerException.

Any suggestion will be appreciated!

```
   -----------in my jsp page:
```

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

// Check if radio buttons exists
    if ($('#centralAdmintype').length > 0) {
        $('#unitOption').attr('disabled', true);
        $('#centralAdmintype').bind('click', function() {
            var checkval = $('#centralAdmintype').is(":checked");
            if (checkval) {
                $('#unitOption').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#unitOption').data('unitId', "0");
            }
        });
        $('#localAdminType').bind('click', function() {
            var checkval = $('#localAdminType').is(":checked");
            if (checkval) {
                $('#unitOption').removeAttr('disabled');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

----------- In body tag

```
<logic:equal name="unitSelectionForm" property="centralAndLocalRoles" value="true">

   <html:radio name="unitSelectionForm" id="centralAdmintype" property="centralRole"   value="0" />Central    
   <html:radio name="unitSelectionForm" id="localAdminType" property="localRole" value="1" />Local
```

------------in my Action form I have:

```
protected ActionForward doExecute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws TechnicalException {
    String forward = DispatchStrings.FORWARD_SUCCESS;
    UnitSelectionForm unitSelForm = (UnitSelectionForm) form;
    unitSelForm.setCentralAndLocalRoles(true);

    boolean hasRadioButton =false;
    boolean hasCentralRole = false;
    boolean hasLocalRole = false;
    hasRadioButton = unitSelForm.getCentralAndLocalRoles();

    if (hasRadioButton) {
        hasCentralRole = unitSelForm.getCentralRole();
        hasLocalRole = unitSelForm.getLocalRole();
    }           
    try{
        if(hasRadioButton && hasCentralRole){
            forward = DispatchStrings.FORWARD_SUCCESS;
        }
```

------------- in my Bean class

```
  public class UnitSelectionForm extends SaltValidatorForm 

    {
      private Integer unitId;
      private OptionForm units[];
      private String loginname;
      private Integer administratorType;
      private Boolean centralRole;
      private Boolean localRole;
      private Boolean centralAndLocalRoles;
```

Comment: Can u post your stacktrace(error log), It would be helpful to rectify your issue.

Comment: @Vinoth                                      java.lang.NullPointerException at se.apoteket.salt.action.SelectUnitAction.doExecute(SelectUnitAction.java:70)

Comment: What i am expecting from your stacktrace is the line/code which making the nullpointer exception in your doExecute method.